# Как получить класс из класса selenium?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parse

я не могу получить класс из класса Selenium.
К примеру есть такая html страница

```html
<div class="element">
   <li class="first_name"> Иван </li>
   <li class="second_name"> Иванов </li>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"element").get_attribute("first_name")
но не выходи.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "element").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "first_name")
```

Если вам нужен не сам элемент, а текст "Иван" - добавьте `.text`:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "element").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "first_name").text
```

Comment: спасибо большое, где вы были раньше?) я уже сам разобрался давно)))